# Repeat javascript function using multiple variables

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure how to best explain what I am trying to do, so I'll put together a quick example.

Let's say I have a JavaScript function like this:

```
function myFunction(){
    doSomething('text string here');
}
```

I need to repeat this function at a specified interval. I can do that with setTimeout.

However, the text string I need to use is not just one single string, I have three. So my function would kind of look like this:

```
function myFunction(){
    var stringOne = "My first string";
    var stringTwo = "My second string";
    var stringthree = "My third string";

    doSomething(*string variable name here*);
}
```

So I need to call the function, let's say every 10 seconds, but each time it runs it needs to use the next text string, in order.

So I need to call:

```
myFunction, and have it use stringOne.
myFunction, and have it use stringTwo.
myFunction, and have it use stringThree.
And then start back at the first one again.
```

I could write three separate functions, and tie them together in a loop using setTimeout, but it seems like there should be a better solution.

Comment: Use an array!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a closure for the counter.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var counter = 0,
        fn = function () {
            var array = ["My first string", "My second string", "My third string"];
            console.log(array[counter]);
            counter++;
            counter %= array.length;
        };
        fn();
    return fn;
}
setInterval(myFunction(), 2000);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the reason for your last code change? The code you had posted previously seems to be working? One further question, how would I get that function to run immediately the first time, and then at the specified interval after that?

Comment: You can use `setTimeout` with recursion

Comment: @Nina, by any chance have you used `array.entries`? How do you reset iterator to `0`? [Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/h4orbtvs/1/)

Comment: @SherwinFlight, while working, the couter loops infinitely, that may makes problems in future by leaving the modulo calculation. now it's cleaner with a named array and the length of the array for modulo.

Comment: @Rajesh, your proposal works, but does not continue.

Comment: @NinaScholz That was the question. How to reset iterator to `0`. I'm not sure if its the correct way but I have re-initialise it. Was hoping you must know.

Comment: @Rajesh, i would not use iterators in this case. btw, `array#values()` would be better without key.

Comment: @NinaScholz I tried moving the setInterval call to inside myFunction, as the last line inside that function. I then tried calling myFunction() directly. I'm trying to run the script immediately on load, and then AFTER that at the specified interval.

Comment: @Rajesh - you could use generators or custom iterators in ES6, something [**like this**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/69pskkad/1/), but it's mostly just golfing.

Comment: @SherwinFlight, i don't get you. what is your problem?

Comment: I'm trying to run the function immediately, then after that at a set interval. I have your code working as-is, but am having trouble getting it to run the first time without delay.

Comment: For some reason when I call the function directly like that, it doesn't run. No errors in my JS console. Hmm

Comment: it starts now with a first call immediately.

Comment: @NinaScholz I guess using `setTimeout` to call itself would rather suit here.

Comment: @Rajesh, while i am a great fan of recursions, `setInterval` works better for fixed invervals than `setTimeout` and countinuous calls, because it does not uses the stack more than necessary.

Comment: @NinaScholz Where do you get this much knowledge from. Do you take apprentice? But jokes apart, really appreciate you taking time to explain things.

Answer (score 1):

just use a global variable to track the current string:

```
currentString = 0;
```

then after each call increase the value and modulo it:

```
function myFunction(){
    switch(currentString){
    //print the current string
    }

    currentString = (currentString + 1) % 3;
}
```

Comment: yeah, true that:)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myFunction(strings){
  var ii = 0
  function iterate(){
    // increment or reset the iterator
    doSomething(strings[ii++ % strings.length])
    // call it again after 1 second (change this)
    setTimeout(iterate, 1000)
  }
  // kick off the iteration of your strings
  iterate()
}

function doSomething(val) {
  console.log(val)
}

// init the iterator with your strings
myFunction([
 'myFunction, and have it use stringOne.',
 'myFunction, and have it use stringTwo.',
 'myFunction, and have it use stringThree.'
])
```

Comment: why would you reinvent modulo?

Comment: Cool didn't think of that. Much cleaner

Comment: you should still use `strings.length`

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive function with incrementing index

```js
(function myFunction(i){
   var arr = ["My first string", "My second string", "My third string"];
   
   setTimeout(function() {
       doSomething( arr[i = i < arr.length ? i : 0] );
       myFunction(++i);
    }, 1000);
})(0);

function doSomething(str) {
    console.log(str)
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that **setTimeout** evaluates the passed string inside. Bad for concerning security sides.

Comment: @bash0ne - why would `setTimeout` evaluate anything, unless you pass it a string ?

Comment: @bash0ne - true story how? Do you still think this evaluates the code inside the timeout ?

Comment: It is possible to pass the setTimeout function a string in the first parameter which must go through `eval()`. So yes

Comment: I'm not passing a string, but an anonymous function, so how is that even remotely relevant ?

Comment: I know, I just wanted to mention that for the OP because you could pass a string also, it does of course not match your implementation. I should have added this comment to the base question maybe.

Answer (score 0):

No need for closures whatsoever; Not mentioned but i have also added a timeout. Just do like this;

```js
var array = ["My first string", "My second string", "My third string"],
      sid;
function runner(i){
  console.log(array[i=i%array.length]); // i hate i growing indefinitely
  sid = setTimeout(_ => runner(++i),2000);
}

runner(0);
setTimeout(_ => clearTimeout(sid),20000);
```